# Cant activate Applicaion Insight (nor Live Stream Metrics)

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Im running a web app on an Azure App Service.

I go to  --> Settings --> App insight 
First time it said that I needed to restart my web app along with a button that I clicked. It took a while, but now I get the message "Your app is currently offline. Visit it to enable Live Stream". 
[image]

When I click "VIEW MORE IN APPLICATION INSIGHT" I get to a step-by-step-guide on how to install Application Insight in VS (which I have followed)

My web app is running, I can visit it and on the overview page for my app service it says Status : "Running"

Comment: Did you mean you can not use Live Metric Stream? Have you tried to restart your project?

Comment: Thanks for your reply:) Well,I cant see *any* app insight metrics, but in this specific case, I was looking to see LIve Metrics Stream. I did test to restart the app now, but no difference.

Comment: It seems that the Live Metrics Stream is in portal. And have you set the InstrumentationKey  of app insight? Also try to update to the latest version of the Application Insights package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-live-stream) about how to open Live Stream in portal. And you could could check these ways if you want to use Live Stream.

1.Copy the InstrumentationKey  from application insight service.Add it in ApplicationInsights.config in your project:

```html
 <InstrumentationKey>your key</InstrumentationKey>
```

2.Add some custom telemetry data to test.

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("my trace info Home/Index");
            var telemetry = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient();
            RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry();
            telemetry.TrackTrace("Home/Index Main");
            telemetry.TrackPageView("Home/Index");
            return View();
        }
```

3.Run your project in debug mode.

4.Click **Live Stream** in overview in application insight service.

Then you could see the telemetry data in Live Stream:

[image]

Comment: Great! Adding the instrumentationKey to my web.config worked for me, I hadnt heard of that before.Thanks a bunch!